# Is there "rule of 30" in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In the Deep Learning course on Udacity, the instructor mentioned "rule of 30", means that your new method / algorithm ... can be considered as "significant improvement" if it can improve the results on at least 30 items on test set.

However, he did not provide the source. Could you give me the reference for this information?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find such rule also, 
but I believe it's just 0.1% of 30000 in that context

Comment: Thanks, but what is 0.1% (why not 0.2%, 0.3% for instance) and what is 30000?

Comment: +1. How could there even be such a rule? As you point out, some kind of improvement based on a percentage of the test cases might be a reasonable rule of thumb, but an absolute number?

Comment: we are talking about https://youtu.be/nqEYVzJLR_c?t=31

Comment: sorry it's 1% of 3000 samples. but author believes that improvements in 30 examples in validation set is "significant". it's pure assumption, and valid only for given set